# How to access different Object with variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to get values (result) from dictionnaries with variable1( the name of the dictionnary that the user enter.) 
Please do anyone know? I would help a lot because I have more than 300 dictionnaries. 
Cheers

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    variable1=req.query['variable1']
    var dictionnary1 = {one:0.2187, two:0.1148};
    var dictionnary2 = {one:0.3257, two:0.1234};

function calculate(){
        result=variable1.one
}
```

calculate()

Comment: I would like that If the user enter "dictionnary1" the function calculate will return 0.2187

Comment: may you try to explain what exactly you mean? do you want to know how to get a parameter from the request? do you want to know how to dynamically add entries to a dictionary (fields in an Object)?

Comment: Use an array of dictionaries and access them by index.

Answer (score 2):

*(Side note: "dictionary" has only one 'n' in it. I'm guessing you've translated your code from another language into English. I went back and forth, but I think it's probably best that I use **your** spelling in the code portions of this answer.)*

Put the dictionaries in an object or `Map` with the dictionary name as the key (do this **once**, outside the `get` callback):

```
// Object
var dictionnaries = {
    dictionnary1: {one:0.2187, two:0.1148},
    dictionnary2: {one:0.3257, two:0.1234}
};

// Map
var dictionaries = new Map([
    ["dictionnary1", {one:0.2187, two:0.1148}],
    ["dictionnary2", {one:0.3257, two:0.1234}]
]);
```

...then in the `get` callback, use `variable1` to look up the dictionary:

```
// Using an object
var dictionnary = dictionnaries[variable1];

// Using a Map
var dictionnary = dictionnaries.get(variable1);
```

...and pass that to `calculate` as an argument:

```
var result = calculate(dictionnary);
```

...where `calculate` looks like (I assume it's more complex than this):

```
function calculate(dictionnary) {
    return dictionnary.one;
}
```

E.g., something like:

```
var dictionnaries = {
    dictionnary1: {one:0.2187, two:0.1148},
    dictionnary2: {one:0.3257, two:0.1234}
};

function calculate(dictionnary) {
    return dictionnary.one;
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var variable1 = req.query['variable1'];
    var dictionnary = dictionnaries[variable1];
    var result = calculate(dictionnary);
    // Use `result` in the response...
});
```